# How does redirection of functional component of react actually work?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to implement on Click authentication and then redirect. Here is what I have done. The onclick function verifies the data from backend but after I get the response, I am not able to redirect. Can someone help?

I have this onClick function:

```
onClick={async(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        loading(true);
        const JSONString = {
            email:props.Email,
            _id:details._id,
            Credits:details.Credits,
            password:details.Password
        }
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/make-a-transaction',{
            method: 'POST',
            headers:{
              'Content-Type':'application/json'
             },
             body:JSON.stringify(JSONString)
         });

        const content = await response.json();
        loading(false);
        //console.log(content);
        Auth.login(content);
        e.history.push("/login-props-test");
      }}
```

when I try to redirect it shows me following error:
[image]

if i use `props.history.push();`

[image]

Can someone point me out what exactly am I missing?

Here is the full snippet for reference:

```
function PrettyTable(props)
{

    const FetchedData = props.Data;
    const SelfData = props.selfData;
    const [PasswordPrompt,updatePasswordPrompt] = useState(false);
    const [loaded,loading] = useState(false);

    const [details,setpurchaseDetails] = useState({
        _id:null,
        Credits:null,
        Password:null,
    });

    return(
        <div>
        <h3 className="My-Table-Details-01">Industrial Performance</h3>
        <table className="Pretty-Table">
        {TableHeaders.map(header=>{
            return(<th className="Pretty-Table-Header">{header}</th>);
        })}
        {
            FetchedData.map(props=>{
                return(<tr className="Pretty-Table-Row">
                    <td className="Pretty-Table-Body">
                    {props.Registerar_UserName}
                    </td>
                    <td className="Pretty-Table-Body">
                    {props._id}
                    </td>
                    <td className="Pretty-Table-Body">
                    {props.Allowance}
                    </td>
                    <td className="Pretty-Table-Body">
                    {props.Credits}
                    </td>
                    </tr>);
            })
        }
        </table>
        <h3 className="My-Table-Details">My Details</h3>
        <table className="Pretty-Table">
        {
            MyTableHeaders.map(header=>{
                return(<th className="My-Pretty-Table-Header">{header}</th>);
            })
        }
        (<tr className="Pretty-Table-Row">
        {
            SelfData.map(detail=>{
                return(<td className="Pretty-Table-Body">
                {detail}
                </td>);
            })
        }
        </tr>
        </table>
        <div className="Purchase-Reuqester">
        <div>
        <Form.Group className="Purchase-Reuester-Column" key={1} autoComplete="off" controlId="PurchaseEntry">
        <Form.Label>Industry-ID</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Enter Industry-ID"
        value={details._id} onChange={val=>{setpurchaseDetails({...details, ["_id"]: val.target.value});}}/>
      </Form.Group>
      <Form.Group className="Purchase-Reuester-Column" key={2} autoComplete="off" controlId="PurchaseCredit">
        <Form.Label>Water Drops</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Enter Water Drops"
        value={details.Credits} onChange={val=>{setpurchaseDetails({...details, ["Credits"]: val.target.value});}}/>
      </Form.Group>
      {PasswordPrompt?<div>
        <div className="Purchase-Reuqester">
        <Form.Group className="Purchase-Reuester-Column" key={3} autoComplete="off" controlId="Password">
        <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password"
        value={details.Password} onChange={val=>{setpurchaseDetails({...details, ["Password"]: val.target.value});}}/>
      </Form.Group>
        </div>
        {loaded?<Button className="Purchase-Reuqester"
        variant="primary" disabled>
        <Spinner
          as="span"
          animation="border"
          size="sm"
          role="status"
          aria-hidden="true"
        />
        <span className="sr-only">Loading...</span>
      </Button>:<Button className="Purchase-Reuqester" onClick={async(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        loading(true);
        const JSONString = {
            email:props.Email,
            _id:details._id,
            Credits:details.Credits,
            password:details.Password
        }
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/make-a-transaction',{
            method: 'POST',
            headers:{
              'Content-Type':'application/json'
             },
             body:JSON.stringify(JSONString)
         });

        const content = await response.json();
        loading(false);
        //console.log(content);
        Auth.login(content);
        props.history.push("/login-props-test");
      }}>Purchase</Button>
    }
        </div>:<div className="Purchase-Reuqester">
        <Button className = "Purchase-Requester-Column" onClick={
            e=>{
                e.preventDefault();
                updatePasswordPrompt(true);
            }
        }>Procceed</Button>
        </div>}
      </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default PrettyTable;
```

Tried to push via props as well but doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: use props.history.push();

Comment: The variable `e` is the click event. There's no history prop on a click event. You want to just push straight to the history object.

Comment: tried that as well. getting the same error on `props.history.push` as well

Comment: Are you using the useHistory hook? If you are, there's no such thing as props.history. like I said, just push straight to the history object. `history.push`. No props needed. It would help if you showed us the whole component. Where are you defining `history`?

Comment: log the props to see what returns

Comment: I don't see history defined anywhere in your component. History is not part of react, it is imported from react router.

Comment: Hmm, actually I want to do a redirect to a specific route from the function component (which I have shown above) Can you tell me the right way to do that?

Comment: also your naming for the setter of your `loading` useState hook is bad. You've called the setter function `loading` and the variable `loaded`. Please use convention, such as `[loaded, setLoaded]...`.

Comment: I see, thank you very much for the help and advice, will update the naming. Also, my issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the component in `withRouter` or use the `useHistory` hook

**useHistory (hook)**

`import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";`

```
let history = useHistory();
history.push("/login-props-test");
```

**withRouter (HOC)**

`import { withRouter } from "react-router";`

```
export default withRouter(PrettyTable);
```

Then access it through props

```
props.history.push("/login-props-test");
```

The docs are [here](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory)